# How to get check with multiple value to one input

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code to get value from check field..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("change keyup mouseup", "#title", function(){
        $("#alias").val($("#title").val())
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/javasalden/vf4uzjhp/

How to complete this code to show:

- If i check "HONDA" and "AUDI":

> Output: Toyota, Honda, Audi

- If i uncheck Honda

> Output: Toyota, Audi

Comment: You mean you have to dipslay the other the two values when you click the checkbox?

Comment: Code needs to make sense, and the code you wrote doesn't. [Take a look at my implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/vf4uzjhp/1/), you should be able to read it and understand more or less what it does without any explanation.

Comment: Please include all relevant code **in the question itself**. Don't just link to an external site. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should do the trick.

```
     <input class="has-value m-r"  id="title"  value="Toyota" type="checkbox">Toyota
     <input class="has-value m-r"  value="Honda" type="checkbox">Honda
     <input class="has-value m-r"  value="Audi" type="checkbox">Audi   
      <br><br>
   <input class="  " name="alias" id="alias" > 
   <br><br>
   if i check "HONDA" and "AUDI"<br><br>

   result input will like this Toyota, Honda, Audi
   <br><br><br>
   if i Uncheck Honda
   <br><br>
   result will like this Toyota, Audi




$(document).ready(function(){
                $('.has-value').click(function() {
                        var t = "";

                     $('.has-value:checked').each(function() {
                         if( t== "") {
                            t = $(this).val();
                         }
                         else {
                           t = t + ","+ $(this).val();
                         }
                     });

                     $('#alias').val(t);

                })
            });
```

Comment: how to specify check as result..

i have 2 item 

Property and car

property check is = home, land
cars check is = Toyota, Honda, audi

how to specific result cars..

because, i check in checkbox property.. it olso shown in result car..

Comment: Don't understand

Comment: Add a class unique to the cars checkboxes and then use that class instead of the .has-value

Answer (score 2):

Check the below code. You need to get all the `checked` and append the values in the input field:

```js
var checkboxes = $(".has-value");
checkboxes.on("change", function() {
  $("#alias").val(
    checkboxes.filter(":checked").map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join(", ")
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="has-value m-r" id="title" value="Toyota," type="checkbox">Toyota
<input class="has-value m-r" value="Honda," type="checkbox">Honda
<input class="has-value m-r" value="Honda," type="checkbox">Audi
<br><br>
<input class="  " name="alias" id="alias">
<br><br> if i check "HONDA" and "AUDI"<br><br> result input will like this Toyota, Honda, Audi
<br><br><br> if i Uncheck Honda
<br><br> result will like this Toyota, Audi
```

Comment: how to specify check as result..

i have 2 item 

Property and car

property check is = home, land
cars check is = Toyota, Honda, audi

how to specific result cars..

because, i check in checkbox property.. it olso shown in result car..